Defining a general distribution over a planar curve
I'm trying to understand how to define an arbritrary distribution over a curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$. To achieve this goal I define a distribution over the unitary interval $[0,1]$ in terms of a probability density $p_\alpha(\alpha)$, then I map a random sample $\alpha\sim p_\alpha(\alpha)$ via a suitable map $\varphi(\alpha)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $\dot{\varphi}(\alpha)\triangleq \frac{\text{d}\varphi}{\text{d}\alpha}$ be the derivative of $\varphi(\alpha)$.
To get a concrete sense about my problem, consider the initial toy problem of defining a uniform distribution over a curve that is the union of two consecutive straight segments.
Let $V_1,V_2,V_3\in\mathbb{R}^2$ be three arbitrary vertices and let $L_i\triangleq \lVert V_{i+1}-V_i\rVert$, $L\triangleq L_1+L_2$.
I've done some experiment with my laptop and a at according to the results it seems that there at least two different solutions to define a uniform distribution over the current curve.
Solution 1
The first uniform sampler is given by
\begin{equation}
\varphi_1(\alpha)\triangleq \begin{cases}
\hfil \frac{L(V_2-V_1)}{L_1}\,\alpha+V_1 & \text{ if } \alpha\in[0,L_1/L) \\
\hfil \frac{L(V_3-V_2)}{L_2}\,\alpha+V_2 & \text{ if } \alpha\in[L_1/L,1]
\end{cases}\\
p_{\alpha,1}(\alpha)\triangleq \mathcal{U}(\alpha;[0,1])
\end{equation}
Solution 2
The second uniform sampler is given by
\begin{equation}
\varphi_2(\alpha)\triangleq \begin{cases}
\hfil 2(V_2-V_1)\,\alpha+V_1 & \text{ if } \alpha\in[0,1/2) \\
\hfil 2(V_3-V_2)\,(\alpha-1/2)+V_2 & \text{ if } \alpha\in[1/2,1]
\end{cases}\\
p_{\alpha,2}(\alpha)\triangleq \frac{L_1}{L}\mathcal{U}(\alpha;[0,1/2])+
\frac{L_2}{L}\mathcal{U}(\alpha;[1/2,1])
\end{equation}
Observation
The two samplers share the following properties

It seems that the two samplers generate points uniformly distributed over the curve;
For both samplers $i=1,2$, the normalized product
\begin{equation}
p_{\ast,i}(\alpha)\triangleq \frac{\lVert \dot{\varphi}_i(\alpha)\rVert\,p_{\alpha,i}(\alpha)}{
\int_0^1 \lVert \dot{\varphi}_i(\beta)\rVert\,p_{\alpha,i}(\beta)\text{ d}\beta}
\end{equation}
is equal to
\begin{equation}
p_{\ast,i}(\alpha)=\mathcal{U}(\alpha;[0,1]).
\end{equation}
and seems to be the density of $\varphi(\alpha),\alpha\sim p_\alpha(\alpha)$.

An attempt to give sense to the facts
The first problem is to clarify what is a uniform distribution over a curve $\mathcal{C}\triangleq\{\varphi(\alpha)\}_{\alpha\in[0,1]}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The idea is to consider the pseudo-pushforward measure
\begin{align}
\tag{1}
\varphi_\ast(\mu)(S)&\triangleq \int_{\varphi^{-1}(S\cap\mathcal{C})} \lVert \dot{\varphi}(\alpha)\rVert \text{ d}\alpha\\
\mu(\mathcal{A})&\triangleq \int_\mathcal{A} \text{d}\alpha
\end{align}
for all measurable sets $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$. This measure returns the length of curve obtained by the intersection of $S$ and the generic curve. Based on $(1)$, the uniform probability measure on the curve $\mathcal{C}$ is given by
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}_\ast(S)\triangleq \frac{\varphi_\ast(\mu)(S\cap\mathcal{C})}{\varphi_\ast(\mu)(\mathcal{C})}= \int_{\varphi^{-1}(S\cap\mathcal{C})} \frac{\lVert \dot{\varphi}(\alpha)\rVert}{
\int \rVert\dot{\varphi}(\beta)\rVert\text{ d}\beta
}\text{d}\alpha
\end{equation}
Accordingly $\mathbb{P}_\ast(S)$ admits a probability density, which is given by
\begin{equation}
p_\ast(\alpha)\triangleq  \frac{\lVert \dot{\varphi}(\alpha)\rVert}{
\int_0^1 \rVert\dot{\varphi}(\beta)\rVert\text{ d}\beta}.
\end{equation}
Now the second problem is given by the question: what is connection between the density $p_\ast(\alpha)$ and the probability density $p_\alpha(\alpha)$? Note that $(1)$ can be written in the following more general form
\begin{align}
\tag{2}
\varphi_\ast(\mathbb{P}_\alpha)(S)&\triangleq \int_{\varphi^{-1}(S\cap\mathcal{C})} \lVert \dot{\varphi}(\alpha)\rVert\,p_\alpha(\alpha) \text{ d}\alpha\\
\mathbb{P}_\alpha(\mathcal{A})&\triangleq \int_{\mathcal{A}} p_\alpha(\alpha)\text{ d}\alpha\\
\end{align}
where on $[0,1]$ it is considered the particular probability density
\begin{equation}
p_\alpha(\alpha)\triangleq \mathcal{U}(\alpha;[0,1])
\end{equation}
According to $(2)$, the density of the pushforwad probability measure is
\begin{equation}
\tag{1.1}
p_\ast(\alpha)\triangleq \frac{\lVert \dot{\varphi}(\alpha)\rVert p_\alpha(\alpha)}{\int_0^1 \lVert \dot{\varphi}(\beta)\rVert p_\alpha(\beta)\text{ d}\beta}
\end{equation}
which expresses the relation between the density of $\varphi(\alpha)$, i.e. $p_\ast(\alpha)$, and $p_\alpha(\alpha)$. Moreover, if $(1.1)$ is correct, it expresses how to generate any desired distribution on $\mathcal{C}$ (i.e. $p_\ast(\alpha)$) in terms of $\varphi(\alpha)$ and $p_\alpha(\alpha)$.
The tricky part
Since $\varphi(\alpha)$ is a function which maps $\alpha$ over the curve $\mathcal{C}$, the following equalities hold
\begin{align}
\textrm{Prob}(\psi(\alpha)\in S)&= \textrm{Prob}(\psi(\alpha)\in (S\cap\mathcal{C}))\\
&=\textrm{Prob}(\alpha\in \varphi^{-1}(S\cap\mathcal{C}))\\
&=\int_{\varphi^{-1}(S\cap\mathcal{C})} p_\alpha(\alpha)\text{ d}\alpha
\end{align}
on the other hand my intuition tells me that
\begin{align}
\textrm{Prob}(\psi(\alpha)\in S)&=\mathbb{P}_\ast(S)\\
&=\int_{\psi^{-1}(S\cap \mathcal{C})} p_\ast(\alpha)\text{ d}\alpha
\end{align}
from which follows the pretty strange equality $p_\alpha(\alpha)=p_\ast(\alpha)$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\tag{2.1}
p_\alpha(\alpha)=\frac{\lVert \dot{\varphi}(\alpha)\rVert p_\alpha(\alpha)}{\int_0^1 \lVert \dot{\varphi}(\beta)\rVert p_\alpha(\beta)\text{ d}\beta}
\end{equation}
which seems to make sense only in the uniform case $p_\alpha(\alpha)=\mathcal{U}(\alpha;[0,1])$.
Questions

Is it correct my derivation of $(1.1)$?
If the derivation of $(1.1)$ is correct and holds not for just $p_\alpha(\alpha)=\mathcal{U}(\alpha;[0,1])$, how do you explain $(2.1)$?
If If the derivation of $(1.1)$ is correct but holds only for$p_\alpha(\alpha)=\mathcal{U}(\alpha;[0,1])$, how do you find the general result for the arbitrary $p_\alpha(\alpha)$?


Because I thought I had thoroughly addressed this issue in your previous question (at least for rectifiable curves, which you implicitly assume here), would you mind explaining how this new one goes beyond that?

In the linked post you suggest a possible solution to define an arbitrary distribution over a curve. I have the suspect that there are multiple ways to achieve this goal. In this post I'm trying to understand which is the condition that generate all possible solutions (which, if my derivation is correct, is $(1.1)$)

(1.1) cannot possibly be appropriate unless you are restricting your investigation to differentiable curves.  The most general case concerns an arbitrary measurable (not even necessarily continuous!) map from an interval into $\mathbb R^2.$
